# Tidy way to get `summary` output per group?

Tags: r, dplyr

My code frequently uses `tapply` and `summary` as shown below:

```r
data <- tibble(
  year = rep(2018:2021, 3),
  x = runif(length(year))
)

tapply(data$x, data$year, summary)
```

The output looks like:

```
$`2018`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.3914  0.5696  0.7477  0.6668  0.8045  0.8614 

$`2019`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.1910  0.2863  0.3816  0.4179  0.5313  0.6809 

(etc.)
```

**Is there a way to get such `summary`-like output in a tibble?**

Desired output, using ugly code:

```r
tapply(data$x, data$year, summary)%>% 
  map(~ as.numeric(round(.x, 2))) %>% 
  map_dfr(set_names, names(summary(1))) %>% 
  add_column(year = 2018:2021, .before = 1)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
   year  Min. `1st Qu.` Median  Mean `3rd Qu.`  Max.
  <int> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1  2018  0.39     0.570   0.75  0.67      0.8   0.86
2  2019  0.19     0.290   0.38  0.42      0.53  0.68
3  2020  0.01     0.35    0.7   0.55      0.82  0.93
4  2021  0.06     0.15    0.24  0.32      0.45  0.66
```

I'm hoping that there is a nice combination of `dplyr` functions to do that better -- my code to get the desired output is hacky.

Of course, I'm hoping not to have to rewrite base R's `summary` function, as below:

```r
summarise(`Min` = min(x), `1st Qu.` = quantile(x, 0.25), ...)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a concise tidyverse way.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  nest_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, summary)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(data)

# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#    year    Min. `1st Qu.` Median  Mean `3rd Qu.`  Max.
#   <int>   <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2018 0.105       0.256  0.407 0.307     0.407 0.407
# 2  2019 0.0354      0.205  0.375 0.313     0.452 0.529
# 3  2020 0.272       0.467  0.662 0.546     0.684 0.705
# 4  2021 0.00564     0.107  0.208 0.252     0.375 0.542
```

---

You can also just convert the table output from your original line. Note that here it converted `year` to character, so you would probably want to change that back.

```r
library(purrr)

tapply(data$x, data$year, summary) %>% 
  map_dfr(c, .id = "year")

# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   year     Min. `1st Qu.` Median  Mean `3rd Qu.`  Max.
#   <chr>   <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2018  0.105       0.256  0.407 0.307     0.407 0.407
# 2 2019  0.0354      0.205  0.375 0.313     0.452 0.529
# 3 2020  0.272       0.467  0.662 0.546     0.684 0.705
# 4 2021  0.00564     0.107  0.208 0.252     0.375 0.542
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Both solutions, in fact. Didn't knwo about `.id` -- very useful, thanks a lot.

Comment: The odd thing is I expected to be able to use `bind_rows(..., .id = "year")` as well, but for some reason it returns `1, 2, 3, 4` instead of keeping the list names. Weird to me.

Answer (score 3):

### Base R solution

Try with `by` followed by `do.call/rbind`.

```
do.call(rbind, by(data$x, data$year, summary))
#           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.
#2018 0.45126737 0.5437956 0.6363238 0.6343376 0.7258727 0.8154215
#2019 0.70134602 0.7425629 0.7837798 0.8227042 0.8833833 0.9829869
#2020 0.02726706 0.3338530 0.6404389 0.4591294 0.6750606 0.7096822
#2021 0.26667973 0.3242120 0.3817443 0.4953048 0.6096173 0.8374904
```

This returns a `"matrix"`:

```
class(do.call(rbind, by(data$x, data$year, summary)))
#[1] "matrix" "array"
```

To get a `"data.frame"`, coerce the return value after, don't use `rbind.data.frame`, it will loose the column names.

```
smry <- do.call(rbind, by(data$x, data$year, summary))
as.data.frame(smry)
```

---

### `dplyr` solution.

A `dplyr` and `purrr` solution could be the following. Note that it doesn't `round`, it coerces the return value of `map_dfr`, which is columns of class `"table"`, to numeric instead.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

tapply(data$x, data$year, summary)%>% 
  map_dfr(set_names, names(summary(1))) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))
## A tibble: 4 x 6
#    Min. `1st Qu.` Median  Mean `3rd Qu.`  Max.
#   <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 0.451      0.544  0.636 0.634     0.726 0.815
#2 0.701      0.743  0.784 0.823     0.883 0.983
#3 0.0273     0.334  0.640 0.459     0.675 0.710
#4 0.267      0.324  0.382 0.495     0.610 0.837
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible tidyverse solution. Same basic idea as Rui's solution above, but a little more verbose since it uses `nest()` and `unnest()` before pivoting back to wide data.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  year = rep(2018:2021, 3),
  x = runif(length(year))
)

df_summary <- data %>% 
  nest_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(
    summary = map(data, ~list(summary(.x))), 
    df = map(summary, ~data.frame(names = names(.x), values = c(.x))),
  ) %>% 
  unnest(df) %>% 
  select(-data, -summary) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = names, values_from = values)

   year  Min. `1st Qu.` Median  Mean `3rd Qu.`  Max.
  <int> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1  2018 0.204     0.351  0.498 0.538     0.705 0.912
2  2019 0.548     0.673  0.798 0.767     0.877 0.956
3  2020 0.228     0.416  0.604 0.604     0.792 0.980
4  2021 0.240     0.314  0.388 0.357     0.416 0.443
```